# Как сделать в airdatapicker, чтобы при перезагрузке сохранялось введенная дата?

Tags: javascript

Использую airdatapicker. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при перезагрузке значение поля со
хранялось.

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <input autocomplete="off"  readonly style="cursor: pointer;" id="dfrom" name="from" class="date_from"  data-min="<?=$min1?>" data-max="<?=$max?>" data-max0="<?=$max?>"  placeholder="" required="" aria-required="true">
                                            <label>Заезд</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <input autocomplete="off" readonly style="cursor: pointer;" id="dto" name="to" class="date_to"  data-min="<?=$min2?>" data-max="<?=$max?>" data-min0="<?=$min2?>"  placeholder="" required="" aria-required="true">
                                            <label>Отьезд</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        
                                        <script>

                                            document.getElementById('dfrom').oninput=function(){
alert("");}
```

Я хотел сделать.Чтобы сохранялось значение в localstorage, но у меня даже не реагирует на изменение инпута. Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

### Легко и просто

Попробуйте у себя. Здесь политика блокирует `localStorage`

```js
let dataInput = localStorage.getItem(`key`) ?? ``;
window.addEventListener(`beforeunload`, (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem(`key`, dataInput);
});

const inputField = document.getElementById(`field`);
inputField.value = dataInput;
inputField.addEventListener(`input`, (event) => {
  dataInput = inputField.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="field" type="text">
```